# Swift Synchronous API calls

Tags: objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have to make three API calls to server one after another(synchronous). The second API has to be called only if the first one is a success. If the first API fails then I have to stop the flow and show another `UIViewController` with retry and cancel. What should I use and How should I do it?

Comment: Use Operation Queue and manage the dependency using OperationQueue

Comment: There are more than one solutions to your problem. Here are some keywords that you should be looking for: `NSOperation`, GCD, futures & promises, async/await pattern. The way that Apple handles this is by operations that depend on other operations. Use of Promises is quite popular for these tasks and finally async/await maybe the cleanest (cognitive load wise) approach to promises (and what I would suggest you to check first)

Answer (score 0):

Using [TRVSURLSessionOperation](https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSURLSessionOperation) would help you, here is how to do it:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let firstOperation = TRVSURLSessionOperation(session: session, request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "first url")!)) { (data, response, error) in
  // Your completion logic
}
let secondOperation = TRVSURLSessionOperation(session: session, request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "second url")!)) { (data, response, error) in
  // Your completion logic
}
secondOperation?.addDependency(firstOperation!)
queue.addOperations([firstOperation!, secondOperation!], waitUntilFinished: false)
```